# GeoServer 2.2 and KML with multiple layers

Tags: geoserver, kml

I would like to be able to create a single URL that allows the download of three layers in a single KML file. Here's two ways to do that:

- [WMS KML Plain](http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au:8080/geoserver/GCC_cc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=GCC_cc:Power_GCC_Pts,GCC_cc:Power_GCC,GCC_cc:Power_GCC_Polygons&styles=&bbox=515281.09375,5252067.0,526356.4375,5266823.0&width=384&height=512&srs=EPSG:28355&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml%20xml)
- [GeoServer Application Link](http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=GCC_cc%3APower_GCC,GCC_cc:Power_GCC_Pts,GCC_cc:Power_GCC_Polygons)

Both fail. The first complains of un-matched tags in the KML. The other doesn't load any points from one of the layers. The broken layer in the KML works in [OpenLayers](http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/geoserver/GCC_cc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=GCC_cc:Power_GCC_Pts&styles=&bbox=519860.53125,5255538.5,524783.3125,5262444.0&width=364&height=512&srs=EPSG:28355&format=application/openlayers) fine...

Any ideas on how to fix this, what's going wrong and why?

Upgrading GeoServer may happen later but isn't a fix.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a Layer Group then downloading that as KML.